# Send data to controller on ui.select angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select2

i'm trying to select a value from dropdown list and get the data from corresponded select id in angularJs

i have came up with [angular-ui/ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) directives

```
<ui-select ng-model="customer" theme="selectize">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="Customer List">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="customer in customers | filter: $select.search">
            <span ng-bind-html="customer.Name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
            <small ng-bind-html="customer.Id.toString() | highlight: $select.search"></small>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

on my controller i have get customer method

```
$scope.setActiveCustomer = function(customer) {
  customersService.getCustomers(customer).then(function(response) {
    $scope.selectedCustomer = response;
  });
};
```

my problem is

- once i select the customer which event should i use for fire
  setActiveCustomer (like onchange or something). when i use `ng-click`
  event fired many time because `ng-click` using to control activate.
- other thing is how can i set initial value for [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [ui-select FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select#faq), your `ng-model` expression should have a `.` in it, for example:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.customer" theme="selectize">
```

To set the initial value, you could just set the property specified in the `ng-model`, so in your controller:

```
$scope.model = {
  customer: $scope.customers[0] // set the initial selected option
};
```

For the onchange event, you could use `$scope.$watch()` like this:

```
$scope.$watch('model.customer', function (customer) {
  $scope.setActiveCustomer(customer);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi runTarmit solved my first problem amazingly but still i'm stucked with second one

Comment: Do you mean setting an initial value?

Comment: yep. initial value not assign as expected!!

Comment: Could you please show how use set the `$scope.model.customer`? Is the `$scope.customers` available at that time?

Comment: yes it's available but when it bind to select ui it's only shows [object Object]
i have check those objects using firebug it shows initial binded object was  `[Object { Id=1, Name="FirstOne"}]` but it should be something like  `Object { Id=1511, Name="FirstOne", $$hashKey="00H"}`